# Jquery total value keeps getting added up

Tags: jquery, html

I have a total value(720), and a selector that has values, and when you select 1 thing it adds to the 720 so for example I get 740. But if i select something higher or lower it adds to the 740 and not the 720. I found stuff about updateTotal. But I just fooled around with that and couldn't get it to work.

So I hope someone could show me how this can be done. Thanks :)

**My html value output:**

```
<div class="SummaryRow">
  <h1><input type="yeets" name="_mdjm_event_cost" id="yett" class="mdjm-input-currency required" readonly="readonly" value="" placeholder="Totaal €0.00" style="
    height: 100px;
    width: 275px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;"/>
  </h1>
</div>
```

**My html Selector:**

```
<select name="iFenceCorners" id="FenceCorners" class="AutosubmitCalculator" tabindex="3">
  <option value="0" selected="selected" data-price="00.00">Geen hoeken</option>
  <option value="1" data-price="20.00">1 hoek</option><option value="2" data-price="40.00">2 hoeken</option><option value="3" data-price="60.00">3 hoeken</option><option value="4" data-price="80.00">4 hoeken</option>
  <option value="5" data-price="100.00">5 hoeken</option><option value="6" data-price="120.00">6 hoeken</option><option value="7" data-price="140.00">7 hoeken</option><option value="8" data-price="160.00">8 hoeken</option>
  <option value="9" data-price="180.00">9 hoeken</option><option value="10" data-price="200.00">10 hoeken</option>
</select>
```

**My jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  base = 0;
  $("#FenceCorners").on("change", function() {
  var prev = $("#yett").val();
  prev = prev.split('€')[1];

    var total = (base * 100 + $(this).find(":selected").data("price") * 100) / 100; // selector HOEKEN
   total = parseInt(prev) + parseInt(total);
     $("#yett").val('Total €' + total.toFixed(2).replace(/\./g, ',')); // selector value added to total
  });

  $(function() {
    var begin = 720; // start value
    $("#yett").val('Total €' + begin.toFixed(2).replace(/\./g, ',')); // total value
  });
});
```

**A fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/z4v5r09s/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Use `begin` variable each time for adding new selected value to it.

2.`var base` is not needed at all.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var begin = 720;
  $("#yett").val('Total €' + begin.toFixed(2));
  $("#FenceCorners").on("change", function() {
    var prev = $("#yett").val();
    prev = prev.split('€')[1];

    var total = ($(this).find(":selected").data("price") * 100) / 100;
    total = parseInt(begin) + parseInt(total); //use begin
    $("#yett").val('Total €' + total.toFixed(2));
  });
});
```

Working fiddle:-http://jsfiddle.net/u69jyxkm/

Comment: I can not understand why you need "base" variable ?

Answer (score 1):

If you always use 720 just change     `total = parseInt(prev) + parseInt(total);` 

to `total = 720 + parseInt(total);`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  base = 0;
  $("#FenceCorners").on("change", function() {
  var prev = $("#yett").val();
  prev = prev.split('€')[1];

    var total = (base * 100 + $(this).find(":selected").data("price") * 100) / 100; // selector HOEKEN
   total = 720 + parseInt(total);
     $("#yett").val('Total €' + total.toFixed(2).replace(/\./g, ',')); // selector value added to total
  });

  $(function() {
    var begin = 720; // start value
    $("#yett").val('Total €' + begin.toFixed(2).replace(/\./g, ',')); // total value
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><h1>
<input type="yeets" name="_mdjm_event_cost" id="yett" class="mdjm-input-currency required" readonly="readonly" value="" placeholder="Totaal €0.00" style="
    height: 100px;
    width: 275px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;"/>
  </h1>
</div>
<select name="iFenceCorners" id="FenceCorners" class="AutosubmitCalculator" tabindex="3">
  <option value="0" selected="selected" data-price="00.00">Geen hoeken</option>
  <option value="1" data-price="20.00">1 hoek</option><option value="2" data-price="40.00">2 hoeken</option><option value="3" data-price="60.00">3 hoeken</option><option value="4" data-price="80.00">4 hoeken</option>
  <option value="5" data-price="100.00">5 hoeken</option><option value="6" data-price="120.00">6 hoeken</option><option value="7" data-price="140.00">7 hoeken</option><option value="8" data-price="160.00">8 hoeken</option>
  <option value="9" data-price="180.00">9 hoeken</option><option value="10" data-price="200.00">10 hoeken</option>
</select>
```